# View or download PDF from Api Rest fetch

Tags: javascript, api, download

I am trying to finish a download of a PDF from an API Rest. I can't see the pdf completely in a new browser tab, I get a chorme pop up with the message "Error
An error occurred while loading the PDF document."

I have the following:

```
function download_2() {
  var myHeaders = new Headers();
  myHeaders.append(
    "Authorization",
    "mytokennnnnnnnnnnnn"
  );

  var requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: myHeaders,
    redirect: "follow",
  };

  fetch(
    "myAPIRESTurlurlurlurlurl",
    requestOptions
  )
    .then((response) => response.text())
    .then((result) => {
    
      let blob = new Blob([result.data], { type: "application/pdf" });
      var arrayBuff;
      var fileReader = new FileReader();
      fileReader.onload = function (event) {
        arrayBuff = event.target.result;
      };
      fileReader.readAsArrayBuffer(blob);

      var URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
      const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const link = document.createElement("a");
      link.target = "_blank";
      link.href = url;

      //I apend the link element
      document.body.appendChild(link);

      //download
      link.click();

      // Clean and remove the link
      link.parentNode.removeChild(link);
      URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
    })
    .catch((error) => console.log("error", error));
}
```

I've also used the fileReader to then pass the blob to it, but I'm not sure if I'm doing it right.

Thank you for the help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add the `download="true"` attribute to the `href` tag you created ?

Comment: Hi F. Yes, even if I add the attribute it downloads, but the error still appears.

https://imgur.com/kJinYkt

Comment: Hi louis, you can check if the pdf created by the api is not damaged ? because the problem maybe caused by the browser failing to load the pdf document.